# Design pattern of activity history storing

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns, android-activity, history

**Study case:**

If I have for example The library object.
In the library are books.
Every book have common information like Name, Date, .... And some other dependencies like Autor, Reseller, ....

I have Person object.
If Person read the book, then I want make new record into history.

And now the problem, what is better:

1) **Create static record in history with all data from Book entity and his dependencies (In this case If the Book will be changed, then history will not be actual)**

or

2) **Strore dependecy on Book object (In this case history will be actual, but in every request I must look at all dependencies)**

I suppose that Books will be changed offen

And the History will be displayed in Person profile. (This assumption response will **Answer 1**) )

But should be history based on actual Book datas ? Or history should have the information form date where history was created ?

Book and Person are only examples

Comment: You should add a property called ID to a book. Then just store IDs of books that person read. If you want to get book details you can get it by ID. For example you could have a dictionary of book objects where the key is ID obviously ;)
The other approach is to make many to many relation with history object storing info about Person and a book. More info:
http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: @neurotix :) Thx for your answer, but of course All entities have their own Id, but this is not a Question. I know solution, but I want know what is better and when. Read points 1) and 2) in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now the problem, what is better:
>
> 1) Create static record in history with all data from Book entity and
>   his dependencies (In this case If the Book will be changed, then
>   history will not be actual)
>
> or
>
> 2) Store dependency on Book object (In this case history will be
>   actual, but in every request I must look at all dependencies)

Not sure what you actually mean by "actual" here, but the better choice is the one that suits your needs.

With option 1, when you later show the history record in your Person Profile, it will contain the information about the book which was current at the time the history record was created.  With option 2, the profile will show the information about the book that is current at the time the profile is viewed.

Which do you want to see in the profile?

If in fact you want to always show information that was current at the time of the history record creation, this is one of the reasons for building a data warehouse with a time dimension.  If this is what you need, and if it's something you need to do with alot of history data, you might want to look into building a data warehouse separate from your transactional database.

For some information on data warehouses, [this IBM Redbook article](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247138.html?Open) might be useful.

Comment: Thx this sounds useful, have any example or link for building a data warehouse with a time dimension ?

Comment: The IBM Redbook article at http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247138/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm might be useful.

Comment: It works for me, but I've moved it into the answer and linked instead to a higher level that gives a choice between this html format or a pdf version.